# Reentrancy in synchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, reentrancy

**Are synchronized methods reentrant**?

I have this code:

```
public class Main {
    
    synchronized void m1() {
        //some code
        m2();
        //some code
    }
    
    synchronized void m2(){
        //some code
    }    
    
}
```

Say two threads (Thread A and Thread B) try to access `m1()` at the same time. **Thread A** takes *lock* first. After some time **Thread A** calls `m2()`, which is also synchronized on same object.

As I don't want to make any guesses can someone tell me this: Is there any guarantee what will happen when **Thread A** calls `m2()`? I mean once **Thread A** calls `m2()`, does it 'leave lock' at all? Because technically it left method's frame, so will it leave lock as well?

[EDIT]: Does **Thread A** get to run `m2()` every time once it calls it? Or does it leave *lock* so both **Thread A** and **Thread B** would race for their goals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java locks are reentrant. If Thread A holds the lock, then it can start executing method m1. Eventually it will invoke method m2, since Thread A already holds the lock, it does not have to reacquire the lock again to execute method m2. Internally the lock keeps the owner field to track this. Even if the lock is already held, since the caller of m2 is the owner of the lock, the access is granted. This design strategy prevents deadlocks.

Comment: So Thread A leaves lock literally when it is done with all its work? Although that work can be accessing methods on same lock object. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, since synchronized keyword guarantees atomicity.